# My 10-months old male dog's penis doesn't want to retract

Tags: dogs, health, breeding

My 10-months old male dog's penis doesn't want to retract. What do I do now?

Answer (score 3):

If its not retracting a vet visit is warranted, could be something simple and only needs lubricant to be placed back in the sheath or a medical concern that would need surgical correction.  Hard to say without seeing the pet in person.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like a serious issue that should not go ignored. Do you have a vet? Most vet hospitals have an urgent care center which only costs a little more than a regular vet visit. I'd recommend going asap so you animal doesn't suffer.